# Carousel not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a problem with my carousel. It was working perfectly until yesterday, but something happened and now the picture won't .. only the first picture is shown and even if you click the next icons it is still not moving. My jquery is loaded, the console doesn't show any mistakes.

```
<section class="full-screen">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <asp:Image src="~/Images/Carousel/Carousel-4.jpg" alt="Chania" runat="server" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chania</h3>
                    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">

                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/Carousel/Carousel-2.jpg" alt="Chania" runat="server" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chania</h3>
                    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">

                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/Carousel/Carousel-3.jpg" alt="Flower" runat="server" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Flowers</h3>
                    <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/Carousel/Carousel-1.jpg" alt="Flower" runat="server" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Flowers</h3>
                    <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And these are my bundle files:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    // Order of CSS or JS
    // 1. JS
    // 2. CSS

    #region JS / Script
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jQuery").Include(
         "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
        "~/Scripts/google-maps.js",
         "~/Scripts/jquery-smoothScrolling.js",
         "~/Scripts/full-slider.css",                 
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
         "~/Scripts/carousel.js"
       ));

    #endregion

    #region CSS / Style
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/BootstrapCss").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/site.css",
        "~/Content/full-slider.css",
        "~/Content/simplelightbox.css",
        "~/Content/simplelightbox.min.css",
        "~/Content/simplelightbox.scss",
        "~/Content/simple-sidebar.css"
        ));
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Check network for 404 errors

Comment: The problem was I had a custom script which I added to the css file, which I should have added to the page itself. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use 
"~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" or "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"

and use easy way to call javascript like drag and drop your link to your master page or aspx page...,when you called javascript like you called may be its reflect your pageload events so...